# W3 Validation error - table background image - says no attribute for background

Tags: html, doctype

I have lots of errors on our [homepage](http://www.villasdirect.com/index.asp), and I'm working through the list, however there seems to be an issue that is difficult to get around...

I am using this for the doctype:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
```

Which I believe to be correct, but W3 says that the attribute background doesn't exist although we have used `background="/images/blahblah.jpg"` all over the site...

Comment: Maybe you're mistaking the validator output: The attribute exists in your code, it just doesn't exist in the specification.

Answer (score 2):

The `background` attribute (for the `table` element) was an unofficial extension to HTML that never made it into the specification. Use the CSS `background-image` property instead.

Comment: To be exact, the `background` attribute is allowed on the `body` element in XHTML 1.0 Transitional, but not on any other elements. In HTML5 drafts, it is also mentioned as “obsolete” for `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`,`tr`, `th`, `td`. Being flagged as obsolete, it will be reported as an error by an HTML5 validator.

Answer (score 0):

you should use css for styling, e.g.

```
style="background: url('...');"
```

or better yet, use ids/classes and put the styling in an external css files.